# Lithium PHP DocumentSet Caching

Tags: php, caching, memcached, lithium

I'm attempting to cache the results of a query (DocumentSet) in hopes of enhancing performance on my clients application.

So before the find the app will check to see if an appropriate cache key exists and, if so, serve that rather than hitting the DB.

In my had it seems straight forward enough, however upon implementation all I get are time outs.

It appears the app has trouble storing the DocumentSet object into cache?

It's likely I'm missing something blindingly apparent ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you share some code so its easier to see where the problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can't explain why but I'm unable to cache the documentset.

Instead I was forced to cache the documentset->to('array'). Then, while reading from cache create a new DocumentSet object by passing the models schema and the cached array, returning that.

Seems to be working fairly well, if not as elegant as I had hoped.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. The problem is the DocumentSet from the db references a cursor and doesn't have all of the documents pulled down from the server. When you convert it to an array, it makes sure it iterates through the cursor to grab all of the data.

Comment: Assuming you're using MongoDB, watch out for the array conversion casting your MongoId and MongoDate objects to strings and unix timestamps. It sounds like you have a schema, so if defined correctly, that will convert everything back properly when you pull documents back out of your reconstructed DocumentSet.  I created a `dataNoCast` method in my base model that I use when I don't want those native mongo objects to be cast. I'll post a gist in a minute.